# Getting error- 'Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch the `postid` from a Real-Time Database for my Android application.
However, I am not able to do so and keep encountering an error inside my `isLiked()` function:

```
Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
```

**My Code:**

```java
    package com.example.lively.Adapter;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.example.lively.CommentActivity;
    import com.example.lively.Model.Post;
    import com.example.lively.Model.User;
    import com.example.lively.PostDetailFragment;
    import com.example.lively.ProfileFragment;
    import com.example.lively.R;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        public Context mContext;
        public List<Post> mPost;
    
        private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    
        public PostAdapter(Context mContext, List<Post> mPost) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mPost = mPost;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_items, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Post post = mPost.get(position);
    
            Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostImage()).into(holder.postImage);
    
            if (post.getDescription().equals("")) {
                holder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.description.setText(post.getDescription());
            }
    
            publisherInfo(holder.profileImage, holder.username, holder.publisher, post.getPublisher());
            if(post.getPostId()!=null)
                isLiked(post.getPostId(), holder.like);
            nrLikes(holder.likes, post.getPostId());
            getComments(post.getPostId(), holder.comments);
            isSaved(post.getPostId(), holder.save);
    
            holder.profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PEEFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
    
                    ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
    
                }
            });
    
            holder.username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PEEFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
    
                    ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
    
                }
            });
            holder.publisher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PEEFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
    
                    ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
    
                }
            });
    
            holder.postImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PEEFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("postid", post.getPostId());
    
                    ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new PostDetailFragment()).commit();
    
                }
            });
    
            holder.save.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (holder.like.getTag().equals("save")) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child(post.getPostId()).setValue(true);
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child(post.getPostId()).removeValue();
                }
            });
    
            holder.like.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostId())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostId())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            });
    
            holder.comment.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostId());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", post.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            });
    
            holder.comments.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostId());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", post.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            });
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mPost.size();
        }
    
        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView profileImage, postImage, like, comment, save;
            public TextView username, likes, publisher, description, comments;
    
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
                postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
                like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
                comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
                save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
                username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
                publisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
                description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            }
        }
    
        private void getComments(String postid, TextView comments) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postid);
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    comments.setText("View all " + snapshot.getChildrenCount() + " comments");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        private void isLiked(String postid, final ImageView imageView) {
            final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    
            if (firebaseUser != null ) {
                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                        .child("Likes")
                        .child(postid);
    
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_thumb_up_alt_24);
                            imageView.setTag("liked");
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_thumb_up_off_alt_24);
                            imageView.setTag("like");
                        }
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
    
        private void nrLikes(final TextView likes, String postid) {
            DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes")
                    .child(postid);
            reference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    likes.setText(snapshot.getChildrenCount() + "likes");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            });
        }
    
        private void publisherInfo(ImageView imageProfile, TextView username, TextView publisher, String userid) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);
    
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageurl()).into(imageProfile);
                    username.setText(user.getUsername());
                    publisher.setText(user.getUsername());
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        private void isSaved(final String postid, ImageView imageView) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves")
                    .child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.child(postid).exists()) {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_bookmark_24);
                        imageView.setTag("saved");
                    } else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_bookmark_border_24);
                        imageView.setTag("save");
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            });
    
        }
    }
```

**The real time database looks like:**

[real time database for postid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B3FK.png)

I tried to bound the child with different if-else conditions, but it is not working. As we can see from the above code, I am attempting to check before getting into the isLiked function. Still, I see no progress.

Comment: Dear @ritu! Welcome to SO! I've made some edits to your code. Please have a look, especially on the `if (post.getPostId()!=null);` part. That does not makes sense in this form. What was your intention in this if? Also, the methods' body were not closed by `}` curly brackets, I've added them and marked that - hopefully - you left out the remaining code by intention. Let's clarify your code and find a solution! Thank you!

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Your check `if (post.getPostId()!=null)` is meant to prevent `isLiked(post.getPostId(), holder.like);` from being called when `post.getPostId()` is null. However you've written it as `if (post.getPostId()!=null);` and that semicolon at the end terminates the if-statement and the following line is always executed. Remove that extra semicolon and your code will work.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I mistakenly added the semicolon there appologies, but after doing the needful it is still not working.

Comment: @AlexMamo Actually I have pasted the needed code only, I have created kind of Instagram clone. In which user can search other users and follow them, on following another user the posts posted by them could be seen in current user's home profile. But on running the app I am getting that error mentioned above. I tried to use If-Else conditions as well but it is not working. If you are ok then I can share my github link from there you can check the whole project.

Comment: @TamasCsizmadia I tried to put only the needed code which was supposed to have errors, i guess it is not the correct way to do that.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show the code without a semicolon, so we can see it better? Do you get exact same error?

Comment: its done kindly check it now.

Answer (score 0):

As @TamasCsizmadia initially spotted in your code, when you're using:

```
if (post.getPostId()!=null);
//
```

With a semicolon at the end of the line, it means that everything that comes after this line of code is not a part of the if statement scope.

According to an earlier comment, you said that you have removed the semicolon at the end of the line, but you get the same error. Seeing your code confirms the behavior. Why? It's because you aren't using curly braces `{}`, which basically means that only the next line (*) is evaluated as being a part of the if statement:

```
if(post.getPostId()!=null)
    isLiked(post.getPostId(), holder.like); //(*)
//(**)
nrLikes(holder.likes, post.getPostId());
getComments(post.getPostId(), holder.comments);
isSaved(post.getPostId(), holder.save);
```

The indentation in your IDE also indicates that (**). To solve this, use the curly braces like below:

```
if(post.getPostId()!=null) {
    isLiked(post.getPostId(), holder.like);
    nrLikes(holder.likes, post.getPostId());
    getComments(post.getPostId(), holder.comments);
    isSaved(post.getPostId(), holder.save);
}
```

Now all four lines of code are a part of the if statement scope.

Comment: Hey Ritu. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?